# How to manage multiple scenes in easeljs?

Tags: html, easeljs, scene

I am impelemting a game in easeljs. I need to add different scenes in different html files. But I dont know how to do it. I mean, when I clicked an object in a file. It must pass different file and load its functuanilities. I searched the problem but the answers always in the same file with adding and removing different containers.

Comment: I think that you should be able to do that by doing this: `delete <old-stage>; <new-stage> = new createjs.Stage("game")` (replace <old-stage> and <new-stage> with the stages to switch between

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. When you say multiple HTML files, are you referring to content exported by Flash/Toolkit? If so, you will have to do some work to combine the content into one "application". Other than loading HTML files into iframes, there isn't really a straightforward way of loading another HTML file into your application (akin to loading another SWF into a Flash application).

Can you describe more your different scenes, how they are constructed, and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok. My scenes are like options, play etc. But, I want them in different files. I want to load options screen when a button in game menu is clicked. But ı dont know how to do that?